# eBay Bulk Data Exchange API - Get Results/Item Numbers After Adding FixedPrice Item

Tags: ebay-api

Using the eBay Bulk Data Exchange API we have successfully created a job, uploaded the XML, started the job, and see JobStatus of Completed with no errors when looking up the job.

The call was to AddFixedPriceItem (Just one for testing). I need to know the eBay Item Number for this listing, or any error messages for failures.

How do I download a report for this Job that contains this information for all items in the job.

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/bulk-data-exchange/CallRef/index.html#CallIndex

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Please show the Perl script you are using

Comment: I suppose I shouldn't have tagged Perl as Perl is not the problem. The question is what function in the API is used o accomplish what we need. A list of results for any Job posted for all items in the job. Errors and in the case of new listings, the eBay item number assigned to it